# Code Coverage Issue preventing us from adding a RegHandler.cls needed for SSO Setup to Communities

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Trying to set up and allow Office365 users to sign into their perspective community. 
Upon following the instructions, we where not able to finish step "Create a registration handler". 
This was due to a code coverage issue in our active org. We noticed that there where multiple AutocreatedRegHandler cls. Following some articles online we tried to modify the xml file and then save to active org from Eclipse with the Force.IDE plugin. 
We have have multiple errors and can't get rid of the AutocreatedRegHandlers. In order to move forward we need help in cleaning up the AutocreatedRegHandler's and help in how to successfully deploy inbound change sets from sandbox in order to deploy our SSO method for Office365 users.

Error's all related to the following. Seems to be related to ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest

ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest validateCreateUpdateUser System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ProfileId]: [ProfileId] 
Stack Trace: Class.ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest.validateCreateUpdateUser: line 31, column 1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue in one of Salesforce's out of the box test classes. This happens every now and again and there are always people running into the same issues.

A short search for ChatterAnswersAuthProviderRegTest fix led me [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BCekIAG). Check out the suggestion from Derrek Harrison 1.

Comment: It seems that resolution is not working for anyone thanks

Comment: @cloudlover That unfortunate, you can find some more suggestions right [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B04TIAS). Check out the comment from Sebastiano Bertani 8.